# Rewrite rule and page not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to configure apache on my server debian but i'm having problem with rewrite module...
I have activated it through terminal with a2enmod rewrite and phpinfo show that is loaded...

A simply htaccess like this works correctly

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^prova1.html$ prova2.html
```

but if I'll try to use my website this is the error

```
Not Found
The requested URL ........ was not found on this server.
```

My website works correctly on aruba provider with same htaccess file...

I have changed 000-default.conf in apache2 directory adding this line

```
DocumentRoot /home/debian/www/

<Directory /home/debian/www>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

I can't understand where is the problem...

This is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule ^pagina([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /pagina.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload apache2? service apache2 reload

If this doesn't work, try to comment out this line: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews using a #

Comment: Nothing... with comment out line Options Indexes etc.... the result is the same... 
Every change I made service apache2 reload

and htaccess is enabled because with

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^prova1.html$ prova2.html

the rule work...

Comment: You probably have to change AllowOverride everywhere in the configuration to All. If this doesnt work, try to add this, reload apache and  add these lines: `RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3`

Comment: I have changed AllowOverride also in etc/apache2/apache.conf
Directory /home/debian/www and directory /

Nothing...........

Now I have activated 
LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace3

What I must see in the error.log ?